# Как закинуть в модель результат запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, qt

Имеется такой код:

```
QSqlQuery qu(*pDB); // pDB - база данных
qu.exec("SELECT `CitiesAndCommunities`.`CityOrCommName`, `BuildingTypes`.`TypeName`, `TableBuildings`.`CountGov`, `TableBuildings`.`CountComm`, `TableBuildings`.`CountPrivate`"
        "FROM `CitiesAndCommunities`, `TableBuildings`, `BuildingTypes` "
        "WHERE `TableBuildings`.`CityOrCommID` = `CitiesAndCommunities`.`CityID` and `TableBuildings`.`BuildTypeID` = `BuildingTypes`.`TypeID`");
```

Есть некий метод.

```
void DBFacade::setMainTable(QTableView *tbl)
{
    model   = new QSqlTableModel(this, *pDB);
    model->select();
    tbl->setModel(model);
}
```

Если я сразу укажу, какую таблицу показывать...

```
model->setTable("BuildingTypes"); // Есть такая табличка с данными
model->select();
```

То выведет содержимое таблицы. Это мне пока не нужно.

Мне нужно указать результирующую таблицу с первого приведенного кода. Это возможно? Просто выводит, обычно, таблички с индексами, внешними ключами. А хотелось бы выводить сразу с данными, привязанными к ним. Подходит для таких целей QSqlTableModel?

// Извините, писал в спешке, потому и, может, что-то недорассказал. Если что, я скину, необходимые данные, если это поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку `QSqlTableModel` унаследована от `QSqlQueryModel`, а последняя, в свою очередь, имеет метод `QSqlQueryModel::setQuery()`, то выполнение произвольного запроса и последующее наполнение модели-таблицы данными кажется вполне реальным. Единственное, в `QSqlTableModel` данный метод переопределён и объявлен как `protected` с пометкой в справке, общий смысл которой сводится к тому, что использовать его не то чтобы не рекомендуется, но и не приветствуется. Иными словами, `QSqlTableModel` предназначена для работы непосредственно с таблицами, но никак не с произвольными выборками.

В рассматриваемой ситуации я бы порекомендовал использовать т.н. представления (view), которые в некотором смысле позволяют эмулировать таблицу из произвольного запроса. В этом случае можно будет использовать `QSqlTableModel` в штатном режиме. Впрочем, есть и ограничения, но они уже будут исходить от самой СУБД.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а где можно найти материала на эту тему? Я что-то, честно говоря, не совсем понимаю, что мне нужно делать.

Comment: По представлениям в MySql вот например [статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/47031/).

Comment: спасибо. Как приеду домой, попытаюсь впитать информацию

Comment: О, неплохо. Я так понял, что я создаю виртуальную таблицу, прописываю её в setTable(); и загружаю её? Звучит неплохо. Данные же редактировать тогда нельзя будет прямо в таблице(хотя, мне это не нужно)? И ещё один небольшой вопрос(не хочется по такому пустяку создавать тему). Я же могу обработать двойное нажатие на строку таблицы и получить данные с неё?

Comment: Редактировать сможете при определённых условиях, упомянутых в статье на Хабре. Но если в задаче вообще не идёт речи о редактировании модели, то смело используйте `QSqlQueryModel`. Она хотя и только для чтения, но поддерживает любые запросы, какие только доступны для `QSqlQuery`. Что касаемо последнего вопроса - да, можете.

Comment: Ну я как-бы редактировать модель не буду. У меня будут кнопки отдельно "Удалить строку", "Добавить строку", "Редактировать строку". При нажатии будет выводиться окно с необходимыми полями ввода (Если это "Добавить строку", допустим). Далее, при нажатии ОК создается и посылается запрос, далее мы обновляем модель. И всё, нормально, вроде. Легально всё это?

Comment: Абсолютно. Нормальный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за быстрые ответы. Очень сильно вы помогли